# How to maintain multiple references for PhotoImage objects

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to display two image objects in my Text widget. Initially, both objects showed up as empty images. After some research, I learned that I need to keep a reference to the image. I added an extra line to my code. I now see the 2nd image displayed correctly, however the 1st image is still blank.

I suspect my "reference" is being over written during the for loop. Is this the case? And if so, how would I maintain multiple references if I need to display multiple image objects inside a Text widget?

Here is my code so far:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

class TestApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.myParent = parent
        self.main_container = Frame(parent)
        self.main_container.pack()

        self.text_box = Text(self.main_container, height=50, width=80)
        self.text_box.pack()

        image_names = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg']

        for name in image_names:
            img = Image.open(os.getcwd() + '\\' + name)
            img_obj = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            self.text_box.image_create(INSERT, image=img_obj)
            self.text_box.insert(END, "\n")
            # Added this extra reference
            self.text_box.image = img_obj

root = Tk()
root.title("This is a test app")
mainapp = TestApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your reference is being overwritten.

The simplest might be to just add the reference to a list. For example:

```
class TestApp:
    def __init__(...):
        ...
        self.images = []
        ...
        for name in image_names:
            ...
            img_obj = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            self.images.append(img_obj)
```